# Azure Databricks Notebook didn't pass parameter

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a problem here, I need to pass my notebook parameter to other notebook. But I got an error here. I have followed the example from Azure Databricks, but it doesn't work.

This is my Notebook Resources script

```
dbutils.notebook.run('./Test', timeout_seconds=(3600*4), {"current_date": "2022-01-25"})
```

This is my error

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

[Sources](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you specified one argument by name, then you need to specify the rest by name as well (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#api)):

```py
dbutils.notebook.run('./Test', timeout_seconds=(3600*4), 
   arguments={"current_date": "2022-01-25"})
```

Or you can omit the first name:

```py
dbutils.notebook.run('./Test', 3600*4, {"current_date": "2022-01-25"})
```